# ngFor when for new data Angular 8.2.14

Tags: angular, ngfor

Trying to update the html table that iterates the data for each order in a ngFor. I have tried several things including ChangeDetectorRef trackBy and reloadData in a spread operator. I am not getting to far being successful. The trackBy seemed promising but as I kept pushing to solve the endless loop I gave up. I will include some code here and provide more if needed.

```
    getStewartOrders() {
    this.http.get(this.config.data.StewartOrdersUrl).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data.response.orders, "STEWART DATA");
      // debugger;
      this.orderTable = false;
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        let data1 = data.response.orders;
        for(let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
          this.stewartorders.push(data1[i]);
        }
        // this.stewartorders = cloneDeep(data1);
        this.orderTable = true;
      });
      
      
      /* this.stewartorders = data.response.orders.filter(stewart => {
        return stewart.file_seq_nbr == this.fileSeqNbr;
      }); */
      console.log(this.stewartorders, "STEWART ORDER");
      // this.ref.detach();
      this.ref.detectChanges();
      // this.ref.reattach();
    });
  }
  trackOrder(index: number, orders: any) {
    console.log('TRACKBY');
    return orders.order_ref;
  }


    <ng-container *ngIf="orderTable">
                  <tr *ngFor="let orders of stewartorders; trackBy: trackOrder; 
                  let orderIndex = index;"
                  class="row-stewart-results">
                    <td>Stewart Orders</td>
                    <td>{{orders.order_date | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</td>
                    <td title="{{orders.order_ref}}" class="orderRefCell">
                      {{orders.order_ref}}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{orders.product_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{orders.order_status}}</td>
                    <td>{{stewartorders.length}}{{orders.orderedby_name}}</td>
                    <td>
                      <a class="link-text link-import-results" *ngIf="orders.import_sw !== 'Y'" (click)="openStewartImportModal(orderIndex)">
                          <i class="fas fa-file-import text-blue" tooltip="Import"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  </ng-container>


trackOrders(index: number, orders: any):string {
console.log('TRACKTHIS');
console.log(orders);
return orders[index].order_ref
```

}

```
getData() {
this.http.get(this.config.data.propertyFormInfo).subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.form_info = data.response.form_info;
  this.cancel_link = data.response.cancel_link;
  this.next_link = data.response.save_continue_link;
  this.pa_municipalities_link = data.response.pa_municipalities_link;
  this.userName = data.meta.user_name;
  this.userEmail = data.meta.user_email;
  this.meta = data.meta;

  this.propertyInfoForm.get('company_id').setValue(data.meta.company_id)
  this.backtittle_links = data.response.backtittle_links;
  this.eclosing_partners = data.response.eclosing_partners;
  this.standardPermissions = data.response.standard_permission;
  this.fundHolidays = data.response.interface_values;
  this.checkPermission();
  if (data.response.orders.has_stewart_records === '1') {
    this.getStewartOrders();
  }

});
```

}

Stewart Order Form ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

import { BsDatepickerConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { ApplicationConfiguration } from 'projects/framework/src/lib/ApplicationConfiguration';
import { SharedService } from '../../services/shared.service';
import { EcCommonActionscriptModalComponent } from '../../ec-common/ec-common-actionscript-modal/ec-common-actionscript-modal.component';
import { AlertType, ModalAlert } from 'projects/framework/src/lib/ec-common/ec-common-modal-alert/modal-alert';
import { Alert } from '../../ec-common/ec-common-alert/alert';
import { KeyValue } from '@angular/common';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { PropertyInfoComponent } from 'projects/ui-app/src/app/pages/property-info/property-info.component';
@Component({
  providers: [PropertyInfoComponent],
  selector: 'app-stewart-order',
  templateUrl: './stewart-order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stewart-order.component.css'],
})
export class StewartOrderComponent implements OnInit {
  public onClose: Subject<any>;
  transactiontype: any;
  config: ApplicationConfiguration;
  stewartOrderForm: FormGroup;
  isFormSubmitted = false;
  currentTab = 0;
  stewart_forminfo: any;
  form_info: any = {};
  controlCaptions: any = {};
  alert_info: any;
  public dpConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig> = new BsDatepickerConfig();

  buyersList: any;
  fileSeqNbr: string;
  buyersTableSettings: any;
  showBuyyerForm: boolean;
  propertyData: any = {};
  disclimer: any;
  ID: any;
  sellersList: any;
  showSellerForm: boolean;
  sellersTableSettings: any;
  orderSubmitted: boolean;
  fundUploadFileUrl: string;
  isContactingServer: boolean;
  isSubmitting = false;
  zipPlaced = "012345678";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private modalService: BsModalService,
    private sharedService: SharedService,
    private propComp: PropertyInfoComponent,
    public applicationConfiguration: ApplicationConfiguration,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    public modalRef: BsModalRef) {
    this.config = applicationConfiguration;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dpConfig.containerClass = 'theme-dark-blue';
    this.dpConfig.showWeekNumbers = false;
    this.onClose = new Subject();
    this.initForm();

    //this.getStewartInfo();

    this.fundUploadFileUrl = this.config.data.fundUploadFileUrl;
    //this.form_info = this.form_info;
    let productGroup = new FormGroup({});

    this.form_info.product_types.forEach(product_type => {

      if (product_type.allow_multiples) {
        for (const product in product_type.products) {
          productGroup.addControl(product, new FormControl());
        }
      }
      else {
        productGroup.addControl(product_type.name, new FormControl());
      }

    });

    this.stewartOrderForm.addControl('products', productGroup);
   // this.stewart_forminfo = this.stewart_forminfo;
    //this.stewart_forminfo.needed_by = this.sharedService.formatDate(this.stewart_forminfo.needed_by);
    this.stewart_forminfo.needed_by = '';

    this.stewart_forminfo.transaction_types = '1';
    this.stewartOrderForm.patchValue(this.stewart_forminfo);

    this.stewartOrderForm.controls['needed_by'].valueChanges.subscribe(value=>{
      this.validateNeedeBy(value);
    })
  }


  selectedTab(index) {
    this.currentTab = index;
  }

  selectTabBtn(index) {
    if (!this.onTabChangeBtn()) {
      this.currentTab = index;
    }

  }
  onTabChangeBtn() {

    switch (this.currentTab) {
      case 0:
        return this.ValidateGeneralTab();
        break;
      case 2:
        return this.validateIOrderTab();
        break;
      default:
        return '';
        break;
    }
  }

  validateNeedeBy(needed_by) {
    const initialState = {
      message: ''
    };
    let neededby = new Date(needed_by?needed_by:this.stewartOrderForm.value.needed_by);
    let defaultDate = new Date(this.stewart_forminfo.needed_by);

    if (neededby < defaultDate) {
      initialState.message = initialState.message + '  ' + ' Needed by should be more then 5 days';
    }if (initialState.message) {
      const alert = new ModalAlert({ message: initialState.message });
      alert.type = AlertType.Error;
      this.sharedService.addModalAlert(alert);
    }
    return initialState.message;
  }
  ValidateGeneralTab() {
    const initialState = {
      message: ''
    };
    if (!this.stewartOrderForm.value.transaction_types || !this.stewartOrderForm.value.needed_by) {
      initialState.message = initialState.message + '  ' + 'You must select transaction type, product type and Needed by';
    }
    if (initialState.message) {
      const alert = new ModalAlert({ message: initialState.message });
      alert.type = AlertType.Error;
      this.sharedService.addModalAlert(alert);
    }
    return initialState.message;
  }
  validateIOrderTab() {

    const initialState = {
      message: ''
    };
    if (!this.stewartOrderForm.value.street_types) {
      initialState.message = initialState.message + '  ' + 'You must select street type';
    }
    if (initialState.message) {
      const alert = new ModalAlert({ message: initialState.message });
      alert.type = AlertType.Error;
      this.sharedService.addModalAlert(alert);
    }
    return initialState.message;
  }
  getScannedFiles() {
    let data = this.propertyData;
    data.file_seq_nbr = this.propertyData.fileSeqNbr
    data.company_id = this.propertyData.company_id;
    this.http.post(this.config.data.getStewartUrl, data).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.form_info = data.response.form_info;
      const save_needed_by = this.stewartOrderForm.value.needed_by;
      this.stewartOrderForm.patchValue(this.stewart_forminfo);
      this.stewartOrderForm.patchValue({needed_by: save_needed_by});
    });
  }

  onUpload(event) {
    this.getScannedFiles();
  }
  initForm() {
    this.isSubmitting = false;
    this.stewartOrderForm = this.fb.group({
      fileSeqNbr: [this.fileSeqNbr],
      transaction_types: ['', Validators.required],
      transaction_type: [''],
      product_type: ['', Validators.required],
      buyer: [''],
      seller: [''],
      buyer1: [''],
      seller1: [''],
      lender: [''],
      loan_number: [''],
      loan_amount: [''],
      purchase_price: [''],
      street_number: [''],
      street_name: [''],
      specialinstructions: [''],
      unit_number: [''],
      parcel_number: [''],
      subdivision: [''],
      section: [''],
      township: [''],
      range: [''],
      lot: [''],
      book: [''],
      page: [''],
      block: [''],
      street_direction_prefixes: [''],
      street_direction_suffixes: [''],
      unit_types: [''],
      street_types: [''],
      phase: [''],
      acreage: [''],
      needed_by: ['', Validators.required],
      property_type: [''],
      loan_type: [''],
      county: [''],
      building: [''],
      city: [''],
      state: [''],
      zipcode: [''],
      disclaimer_text: [''],
    });

    this.controlCaptions = {
      transaction_type: 'transaction type',
      product_type: 'business segment',
      need_by: 'needed by',
    };

  }
  isFormValid = false;
  validatestewartFrom() {
    this.isFormValid = false;
    if (this.ValidateGeneralTab()) {

      return false;
    }
    if (this.validateIOrderTab()) {

      return false;
    }
    this.isFormValid = true;
    return true;
  }

  submitOrder() {
    this.isFormSubmitted = true;
    if (!this.validatestewartFrom()) {
      return
    }

    this.isSubmitting = true;
    let data: any =

    {
      "acreage": "",
      "apn": "",
      "block": this.stewartOrderForm.value.block,
      "book": this.stewartOrderForm.value.bock,
      "building": this.stewartOrderForm.value.building,
      "county": this.stewartOrderForm.value.county,
      "need_by": this.stewartOrderForm.value.needed_by,
      "loan_type": this.stewartOrderForm.value.loan_type,
      "lot": this.stewartOrderForm.value.lot,
      "order_guid": "",
      "page": this.stewartOrderForm.value.page,
      "phase": this.stewartOrderForm.value.phase,
      "prop_city": this.stewartOrderForm.value.city,
      "prop_zip": this.stewartOrderForm.value.zipcode,
      "property_type": this.stewartOrderForm.value.property_type,
      "range": this.stewartOrderForm.value.range,
      "searchtype": "",
      "section": this.stewartOrderForm.value.section,
      "specialinstructions": this.stewartOrderForm.value.specialinstructions,
      "state": this.stewartOrderForm.value.state,
      "street_direction_prefix": this.stewartOrderForm.value.street_direction_prefixes,
      "street_direction_suffix": this.stewartOrderForm.value.street_direction_suffixes,
      "street_name": this.stewartOrderForm.value.street_name,
      "street_nbr": this.stewartOrderForm.value.street_number,
      "street_type": this.stewartOrderForm.value.street_types,
      "subdivision": this.stewartOrderForm.value.subdivision,
      "township": this.stewartOrderForm.value.township,
      "transaction_type": this.stewartOrderForm.value.transaction_types,
      "unit_from": "",
      "unit_number": this.stewartOrderForm.value.unit_number,
      "unit_to": this.stewartOrderForm.value.unit_to,
      "unit_type": this.stewartOrderForm.value.unit_types,
      "updatenotes": "",
      "loan_amount": this.stewartOrderForm.value.loan_amount,
      "purchase_price": this.stewartOrderForm.value.purchase_price,
      "lender": this.stewartOrderForm.value.lender,
      "loan_number": this.stewartOrderForm.value.loan_number
    }



    let products = [];

    for (const key in this.stewartOrderForm.value.products) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.stewartOrderForm.value.products, key)) {
        if (this.stewartOrderForm.value.products[key]) { // Could be null if no product of this sort selected
          products.push(this.stewartOrderForm.value.products[key]);
        }
      }
    }
    data.product = products.join(',')
    data.saved_documents = this.form_info.scanned_files.filter(file => {
      return file.isChecked
    }).map(file => {
      return file.key
    }).join('|');

    data.borrowers = this.form_info.borrowers;
    data.sellers = this.form_info.sellers;
    this.http.post(this.form_info.submit_link, data).subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data.meta.status != 'SUCCESS') {
        let alert = new Alert({ message: data.meta.status_message });
        alert.type = AlertType.Error
        this.sharedService.addAllert(alert);
      }
      else {
        let alert = new Alert({ message: data.meta.status_message });
        alert.type = AlertType.Success
        this.sharedService.addAllert(alert);
      }
      // window.location.reload();
      this.propComp.reloadStewart();
      // this.propComp.ngOnInit();
      
      // this.propComp.reloadData();
      // this.addData(data);
      // this.onClose.next(this.form_info);
      this.modalRef.hide();
    });

  }

  // public data = [];

  // addData(data){
  //   this.data.push(data);
  // }

  // Need to display some lists alphabetically by the display vvlue
  alphaByValue = (a: KeyValue<number,string>, b: KeyValue<number,string>): number => {
    return a.value.localeCompare(b.value);
  }  
  
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is - is it not displaying anything at all? How are you calling the service? What are the 4 lines at the end of your HTML?

Comment: So that is not just html it is part of the html table that is used to display the stewart orders. There is a component with a form that creates the order and then the page component is suposed to display parts of that data in a table for the user. Currently they have to refresh the page to get the order to show.

Comment: The issue is I have tried to leverage several things to get the ngFor to loop through and get the order recently added. The only thing that works is to call window.location.reload() in the submit function of the stewart modal component. I really do not want to do that. I have tried to call the getStewartOrders() and it does but the ngFor never loops over the array of objects added to the array.

Comment: How and where do you call `getStewartOrders()`? Paste the code block in your question.

Comment: I added the requested code. So basically it just fires an if to check if it has orders then calls getStewartOrders. The issue I am having is the new orders do not show until I refresh. Like the ngFor wont update with new data until refresh.

Comment: Also to add in the modal form to create a new order I also call getStewartOrders but i am not sure that is really the fix for this. I just want the ngFor to refresh and put the new order on the page/ view. I have searched all over stackoverflow and tried many fixes listed as the solution but have not worked. Maybe I did them incorrectly but I am feeling a bit defeated with this one.

Comment: Where do you call `getData()` from - it's impossible to give you an answer when I only have part of the picture.

Comment: I call getData() in the ngOnInit()

Comment: I was hoping this question was a bit easier than this. The real solution I am looking for will take the getStewartOrders and refire the ngFor loop to get it in the table without page refresh. window.location.reload() works but is not the solution.

Also calling getStewartOrders in the modal submit function will not work... I get a slew of errors when I build a full-build on the project. I have a feeling I will need to add all the imports from property-info.compnent into the modal component to call that function.

Comment: I am not a Angular guru I have a few projects under my belt but mostly I come from angularjs and reactjs background. I just want to do this using angular techniques not mix up js to force it and such.

Comment: I am also happy to share my screen with you to inspect the code with me.

Comment: Are you using `onPush` change detection?

Comment: I am not using onPush but I tried to implement this. But I am not sure I did that correctly. I found that the creation of the order was not returning anything. I did see that I got it into the array but would not update the table data on the page.

Comment: I tried OnPush but kept getting errors. I added much more code in hopes I can get this task completed. I am getting the array to update from say 30 to 31 but view only displays 30 even though array has 31. Using TrackBy and ChangeDetectorRef. Do I need to combine this all with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush or Default or is this not needed?

Comment: Just got this error ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

Comment: Don't use OnPush, but if you were using it, it might have contributed to your problem. What you are doing is standard angular and you shouldn't need trackBy or detect Changes. I would suggest creating a Stackblitz.

Comment: I ended up trying data binding with this.stewartorders.push.apply(this.stewartorders, event);

Comment: The issue I now have is to get this to work for the other orders that use EcCommonActionscriptModalComponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by leveraging data binding and pushing to the array by passing the data from module back to the outside commponent:

Button to create order I added:

```
(onNewOrders)="addNewStewartOrders($event)"
```

Method hit after onClose of module

```
addNewStewartOrders(event){
    this.stewartorders.push.apply(this.stewartorders, event);
  }
```

Order button component back from modal:

```
this.modalRef.content.onClose.subscribe((newOrders:any) => {
          console.log(newOrders, 'newOrders STEWART')
          this.onNewOrders.emit(newOrders);
        });

this.onClose.next(data.response.orders);
```